# Get taxonomy description when filtering custom post type

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm using a custom post-type and I am doing the filtering using categories.
Each category has a description and I would like to show the description of the category when the category is selected [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxfOL.jpg)

I found a way to show the description of the taxonomy [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912521/how-i-can-get-custom-post-type-taxonomy-description)

**Html used:**

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
                <div class="lista-portofoliu">
                    <div class="row">
                        
                        <?php while ($pquery->have_posts()) : $pquery->the_post();
                            $term_obj_list = get_the_terms(get_the_id(), 'portfolio_category');
                            $term_classes_a = array();
                            $img_data = array();
                            $img_string = ""; ?>
                            <?php foreach ($term_obj_list as $term) {

                                $term_classes_a[] = $term->slug;
                                $meniu_triggers[] = $term->slug;
                                $meniu_labels[] = $term->name;

                                $img_key = 'imagine_' . $term->slug;
                                $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field($img_key, get_the_id()), 'thumbnail');

                                if ($img_src) {
                                    $img_data[] = 'data-' . $img_key . '="' . $img_src[0] . '"';
                                } else {
                                    $img_data[] = 'data-' . $img_key . '="' . wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field($img_key, get_the_id()), 'full') . '"';
                                }                                    
                                foreach ($img_data as $imagine) :
                                    $img_string .= $imagine;

                                endforeach;;
                            } ?>

                            <?php $term_classes = implode(" ", $term_classes_a);  ?>

                            <div class="col-lg-4 p-1 m-0 item toate <?php echo $term_classes; ?>">
                                <div class=" item-content" <?php echo $img_string; ?> data-imagine_toate="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_id(), 'thumbnail', true); ?>" style="background-image:url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_id(), 'thumbnail', true); ?>')">
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class=" item-overlay">
                                        <span class="item-title">
                                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                                            <br>
                                            <br>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile;
                        ?>
                        
                        <?php
                        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="more_posts" class="btn btn-dark loadMore center-block btn-pachete">Mai mult</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is incomplete. What isn't working and what stops you from implementing your research?

Comment: Every time I use a filter (categories) I want that the first box (where the custom posts are displayed) to display the description of the category(that is written in wordpress)

Comment: Alright. I got you on that first part. What is preventing you from doing just that? You already found how you can output the description, but have you tried to implement it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order everything by portfolio category, then you should first loop over each term in the `portfolio_category` taxonomy.

With each term, create a new query where you use the `tax_query` to only get the posts related to the current term we're looping over.

The result will be that each loop contains the category data and the posts related to that category.

You can output the category description by echoing the `$term->description` value.

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms('portfolio_category');
if (!is_wp_error($terms)) :
  foreach ($terms as $term) : ?>

    <div class="row">

    <?php
    $args = [
      'post_type' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'tax_query' => [
        [
          'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_category',
          'field' => 'term_id',
          'terms' => $term->term_id
        ]
      ]
    ];

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
      
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <?= $term->name; ?>
        <?= $term->description; ?>
      </div>

      <?php
      while ($query->have_posts()) :
        $query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>

      <?php
      endwhile
      wp_reset_postdata();
    endif; ?>

    </div>

  <?php
  endforeach;
endif;
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried the code. So from what I understand this shows the description of all categories. What I need is that only when I select a certain category(filter) to display the description of only the selected category and the items(posts) that have that property. (I'm kinda new to asking questions, please bare with me)

Comment: Ah I see. Well, the same thing would apply to this code snippet, but instead of looping over *all* terms, we would just apply a single term, or an array of terms, to show the description and posts. 

Unfortunately I don't have an example of a filtered value(s). Could you provide it? 

However does the current answer come close to what you meant by your question. It's totally fine that you're new to this. Keep going. :)

Comment: hi, will apply asap, did not get the time with the holidays , thanks and happy new year!